# Rails Cucumber Capybara id/class selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, bdd

So here is my test.

```
When(/^the admin user broadcasts "([^"]*)" to the notification feed$/) do |userBroadcast|
  visit('/broadcasts/new.html')  
  fill_in('.nifty_form', with: userBroadcast)
  click_button('Broadcast')
end
```

I have added into my new.html.erb a class called 'nifty-form' as you can see below.

```
<h1>New broadcast</h1>

<%= form_for(@broadcast) do |f| %>
    <% if @broadcast.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@broadcast.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this broadcast from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @broadcast.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag 'page', @current_page %>

    <div id="broadcast-area" class="main-input-area">
      <p>
        <%= f.text_area :content, cols: "100%", rows: "10", class: 'nifty-form',
                        title: "Broadcast text goes here", autofocus: 'autofocus'%>
      </p>

      <div id="url-part">
        <%= link_to("Shortens URL",
                    id: "split-arrow",
                    title: "Press this to shorten the URL") %>
        <%= text_field_tag :shorten_url, nil,
                           title: "Enter URL that you wish to shorten",
                           size: "50%" %>

      </div>
      <br/>

      <div id="">
        <%= f.submit 'Broadcast', confirm: 'Do you really want to broadcast?' %> |
        <%= link_to 'Back', broadcasts_path(page: @current_page) %>
      </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason, I get the result:

```
Unable to find field "nifty_form" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

I have viewed the source of the rendered page and it is the following:

```
<textarea cols="100%" rows="1o" class="nifty_form" title="Broadcast text goes here" autofocus="autofocus" name="broadcast[content]" id="broadcast_content" style="z-index: auto; position: relative; line-height: normal; font-size: 10.6667px; transition: none; background: transparent !important;" data-gramm="true" data-txt_gramm_id="b763ea7b-2eef-d3c8-b750-a085d2c9ce80" data-gramm_id="b763ea7b-2eef-d3c8-b750-a085d2c9ce80" spellcheck="false" data-gramm_editor="true"></textarea>
```

So seeing this has an ID in the rendered page I decided to write a  test  with that ID like so:

```
When(/^the admin user broadcasts "([^"]*)" to the notification feed$/) do |userBroadcast|
  visit('/broadcasts/new.html')  
  fill_in('#broadcast_content', with: userBroadcast)
end
```

But yet again I am left with the same error message of

```
   Unable to find field "broadcast_content" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Is there a way to print out all the Div's Class's that Capybara can see? How can I debug this problem? Am I correct in assuming that Cappybara follows the link after a button is clicked? and the session is kept alive?

Answer (score 0):

Capybaras fill_in takes the name, id, placeholder, or label text of the input you want to fill_in.  It does not take a CSS selector. In your example that would translate to

```
fill_in('broadcast_content', with: userBroadcast)
```

since the id is 'broadcast_content' not '#broadcast_content'

If you want to use css selectors then you'd need to do something like

```
find(:css, '#broadcast_content').set(userBroadcast) # the :css is optional if your default selector type is set to :css
```

In the latest version of Capybara the locator strings are now optional, and :id and :class options are available, so I believe your initial attempt could also have been written as

```
fill_in(class: 'nifty_form', with: userBroadcast)
```

although since classes are generally not unique on a page you're probably better off sticking with the id

Comment: I have tried all of the above examples and I still get an element not found, I have pasted more of my erb.html file above.

Comment: @Definity it sounds like the textarea isn't actually visible on the page and is being replaced by a JS widget. Is that the case? If so you'll need to interact with the elements of the widget rather than the textarea.